# C++ code compiling error

Tags: c++, encoding

Does anyone know why in:

io.cpp:

```
# include <iostream>
int ReadNumber()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    return x;
}

void WriteAnswer(int x)
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "The answer is " << x << endl;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
int ReadNumber();
void WriteAnswer(int x);

int main()
{
    int x = ReadNumber();
    int y = ReadNumber();
    WriteAnswer(x+y);
    return 0;
}
```

there is no int x in the Readnumber(); forward declaration in main.cpp? when I do put int x inside the brackets, the compiler says that:   ''function does not take 0 arguments''

Comment: Time to take hours to read a good C++ book. In your `ReadNumber` the `x` is a *local* variable.

Comment: "there is no int x in the Readnumber(); forward declaration" because you didn't put it there. And you shouldn't, because it wouldn't match the function definition if you did, which is why you're getting that error message. Function declarations should match function definitions.

Comment: Some serious misunderstanding here but I'm not sure what it is. You declared ReadNumber with no parameters, so you should call it with no parameters. Why you want to add one is a mystery to me. But quite rightly the compiler stops you. BTW there are no 'forward declarations' in your code. Forward declarations are quite advanced, so I would forget about them for now.

Comment: Alright, so if for instance I would have placed another variable in the cout in void not predeclared in the brackets of writeanswer I would have gotten the same error?

Comment: Whatever you write in your function definition doesn't matter at all for the declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int ReadNumber();
```

this function declaration in main indicate that your ReadNumber function takes no parameters and will return an int.

If you add int x as parameter in ReadNumber declaration (in main.cpp) and definition (in io.cpp) :

```
int ReadNumber(int x)
```

your function calls to this function must then include an integer as parameter. That is why you get the message ''function does not take 0 arguments'' : you are calling a function that awaits 1 parameter and yours calls to the function doesnt include any.

Here is an example of ReadNumber function call including a parameter:

```
int YourParamUsedInReadNumber = 0;    
int x = ReadNumber(YourParamUsedInReadNumber);
```

As suggested in comments, you should probably get a good C++ book to get a good grip on programming basics before going further.